# Stop a BufferedReader inside a Runnable Object

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I've got an Object called `IRCConnection`, that implements `Runnable` and contains a `Socket`. I connect to a Server with that `Socket` and read the input with the help of a `BufferedReader`.
I want to be able to stop the `BufferedReader` in order to close the Socket.

**Things i've tried so far:**

- called the `close()` method from another Thread => NPE for the Socket Object
- set `running` to false from another Thread
- set all methods to synchronized
- called `shutdownInput` of the Socket => NPE for the Socket Object
- added `volatile`keyword to `running`
- interrupted the Thread and hoped for it to interrupt the `BufferedReader`
- extend Thread instead of implementing Runnable

  ```
  public class IRCConnection implements Runnable {
  private BufferedReader br;
  private BufferedWriter bw;
  private Socket ircSocket;

  // constructor and other irrelevant methods
  .... 

  // relevant methods
  public void run() {
      // creating socket
      ircSocket = new Socket();
      try {
          ircSocket.setSoTimeout(100);
          // opening connection
          ircSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(getServer(), getPort()));


          br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ircSocket.getInputStream()));
          bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(ircSocket.getOutputStream()));

      String inputLine;
      while (isRunning()) {
          inputLine = br.readLine();
              if (inputLine != null) {
                  doSomething();
                  }
              }
          }
      close();
      } catch (IOException ie) {
          log(ie);
      }
  }

  public void close() {
      if (ircSocket != null) {
              if (ircSocket.isConnected()) {
                  setRunning(false);
                  try {
                  ircSocket.close();
                  } catch (IOException e) {
                  log(e);
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  }

I create the runnable in another object and start it with start the Runnable with `Thread(irc).start()`.

I don't really understand how i could have an initialized and connected Socket in both Threads or at least be able to stop it in one.

Comment: It's enough to `close()` the `Socket`, but in your case you never seem to initialize `ircSocket` to anything. You've also tried a lot of random things, which works with programming about as well as it does with brain surgery.

Comment: It is being initialized in the constructor. And i've only tried things, that other people suggested could work in similiar questions asked here on stackoverflow.

Comment: What constructor? There's no constructor.

Comment: That's just a code snippet, since posting everything would make it unnecessarily large. So this means, that there are other functions, yet me not posting them means, that they are not relevant for this problem.

Comment: You're not qualified to determine what's relevant to the problem, you're the one with the problem. Anyway, my first comment still stands.

Comment: Well, i've tried to use `close()`, as i stated in "the random things, that work  with programming as well as they do with brain surgery".

Comment: Which is why you need to show your code. You're claiming that you're getting "NPE for the Socket Object" which doesn't make much sense. If you mean that `ircSocket` is null, then that's not very likely since you're doing a nullcheck.

Comment: I had the initialization of the Socket object in the run method earlier, that's why i was sure, that it was initialized. Later i moved it to the constructor in order to not have that NPE anymore, which lead to the fact, that the Socket would give me `false` on a `isConnected()` call. But i've solved it. Thanks for the effort though.

Comment: If `inputLine` is null you must break out of the read loop. You don't need `isRunning`, or rather it doesn't do much good, as you will mostly be blocked in `readLine()`.

Answer (score 1):

> called `shutdownInput` of the Socket

This is the correct answer.

> => NPE for the Socket Object

So fix that. Surely you can solve an NPE?